How can I upsert a list in one go with BigQuery .NET?
I have code written for BigQuery. I want to be able to upsert all list elements by sending a list. In order not to be blocked from BigQuery due to query cost and excessive requests, I am trying to do upsert by sending a list at a time and with a single query.
The details of the code I wrote for .NET are shown below. However, I could not finish it and I am looking for information and solution suggestions on the subject. Is it possible to do this? If possible, how and what should I edit? If not, what is the reason?
private async Task UpsertCardHistoryToBigQueryAsync(List<BigQueryCardInfoDto> recordList)
{
    var circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .CircuitBreakerAsync(2, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    await circuitBreakerPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            var query = @"
            MERGE `{_datasetId}.{_tableId}` AS target
            USING UNNEST(@dataList) AS source
            ON target.UniqueId = source.UniqueId
            WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                UPDATE SET source..
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                INSERT (*) 
                VALUES(source..);";

            var parameters = new List<BigQueryParameter>
            {
                new BigQueryParameter("dataList", BigQueryDbType.Array, recordList)
            };

            var jobOptions = new QueryOptions { UseQueryCache = false };
            var queryJob = await _bigQueryClient.ExecuteQueryAsync(query, parameters, jobOptions);
    });
}


This may not be relevant to big query though I assume a similar workflow is possible you may want to look into. In Snowflake we use the GCS storage integrations which allow you to basically query csvs inside of the gcs buckets. We then set up a script that would copy the data from the file into a temp table, then run a similar merge script as you have here to quickly merge (upsert) data into our true sources and then drop the temp table. Works like a charm and minimizes compute time.
I'd recommend trying something like that to see if it works for your purposes.

use CSV helper to take your list and turn it into a CSV memory stream:
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-class-objects/
upload memory stream to gcs bucket
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects-from-memory
move data from gcs to big query into temp table
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#c
now run your merge script.
cleanup any files/temp tables

While UniqueId is a good starting point, consider adding additional conditions to prevent unnecessary updates if only certain fields have changed. This will improve performance, especially if you have a high volume of records. Also ensure that your input recordList doesn't have duplicate records with the same UniqueId. If you're expecting duplicates, you can use a SELECT DISTINCT clause to filter out duplicates before passing it to UNNEST.
Feel free to browse these documentation for MERGE examples that might be helpful to you.
